# C separating text with space

Tags: c, string, strtok

I wrote a code that is supposed to add two roman numerals separated by space. There's some problem, probably with this part (line 93)

```
pch = strtok (str," ");
```

When I put other signs in brackets it works properly. I don't know why. I would be really grateful if somebody could help. (I don't know much about the usage of chars in C)

The part with converting roman numerals didn't paste properly here, but I think my mistake is somewhere in main function.

```
int main() {

    char str[26];
    scanf("%s", &str);

    char * pch;
    int result=0;
    pch = strtok (str," ");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        result+=roman(pch, sizeof pch / sizeof pch[0]);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
    printf("%d",result);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please specify the exact problem that you are facing. That line for `strtok` doesn't really seem suspect. Also I don't think `sizeof pch` is going to help you. `pch` is just a pointer and it's size will always be 8 bytes on a 64-bit system. You are probably looking for `strlen(pch)`

Comment: `scanf("%s", &str);` only reads the first number.  `pch = strtok (str," ");` then always returns `NULL`.  Research `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scanf() only reads until the first space. check out this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-string-input-space-c-3-different-methods/
The most popular method is fgets()